# How to handle abort window in Coded UI test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have a scenario like below:

--Green path
1) Open a form 
2) give path to a file
3) run the process
4) generates output 
5) sucesss messages written to a screen on the form and then
6) Close button enabled.

-- automated above workflow via Coded UI test.

--Red path
1) Open a form 
2) give path to a file
3) run the process
4) doesn't generates output 
5) ABORT window popped up (need to close it before Close button enabled)
6) Close enabled

However to handle above Red path case, I'm unable to use the Automated Coded UI test written for Green path, is there a way to handlde ABORT window in the Green path Coded UI test?

Thanks.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        //my green path recording.
        this.UIMap.GreenPathCode();

        //my red path recodring.
        this.UIMap.RedPathCode();
    }


    public void GreenPathCode()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinEdit uITextBox1Edit = this.UIForm1Window.UITextBox1Window.UITextBox1Edit;
        WinButton uIButton1Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton1Window.UIButton1Button;
        WinButton uIButton2Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton2Window.UIButton2Button;
        #endregion

        // Type '1' in 'textBox1' text box
        uITextBox1Edit.Text = this.GreenPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText;

        // Click 'button1' button
        Mouse.Click(uIButton1Button, new Point(21, 10));

        // Click 'button2' button
        Mouse.Click(uIButton2Button, new Point(35, 8));
    }


    public void RedPathCode()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinEdit uITextBox1Edit = this.UIForm1Window.UITextBox1Window.UITextBox1Edit;
        WinButton uIButton1Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton1Window.UIButton1Button;
        WinButton uIAbortButton = this.UIErrorWindow.UIAbortWindow.UIAbortButton;
        WinButton uIButton2Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton2Window.UIButton2Button;
        #endregion

        // Type '2' in 'textBox1' text box
        uITextBox1Edit.Text = this.RedPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText;

        // Click 'button1' button
        Mouse.Click(uIButton1Button, new Point(35, 10));

        // Click '&Abort' button
        Mouse.Click(uIAbortButton, new Point(51, 12));

        // Click 'button2' button
        Mouse.Click(uIButton2Button, new Point(56, 16));
    }
```

Comment: simple question what code have you tried thus far..??

Comment: i have not tried anything DJ sorry not getting any ideas at all :(...i am trying to capture sAbort window and try to use the code in Green path code :( unfortunately nothing is working

Comment: you will have to at least produce some bit of code so other can get an idea of what it is you are trying to do.. we are not mind readers here

Comment: Sorry DJ added code for your reference,,, in the sample code i am trying to add Abort button case in Green Path Code function, so that when Abort button window pops up i would be able to hanlde that case. 
I am planning to send inputs from a data source hence want to use only one method for this purpose.

Comment: if i am not still clear sorry. i will come up with more information.

Comment: I see the methods but not quite sure how are you really doing anything in regards to creating and a new form and passing a form reference to another Form or Class...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like this? You will of course have to move the code out of the designer file.

```
   [TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    this.UIMap.RedPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText="1";
    this.UIMap.RedAndGreenPath();

    this.UIMap.RedPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText="2"
    this.UIMap.RedAndGreenPath();
}
 public void RedAndGreenPaths()
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    WinEdit uITextBox1Edit = this.UIForm1Window.UITextBox1Window.UITextBox1Edit;
    WinButton uIButton1Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton1Window.UIButton1Button;
    WinButton uIAbortButton = this.UIErrorWindow.UIAbortWindow.UIAbortButton;
    WinButton uIButton2Button = this.UIForm1Window.UIButton2Window.UIButton2Button;
    #endregion

    // Type '2' in 'textBox1' text box
    uITextBox1Edit.Text = this.RedPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText;

    // Click 'button1' button
    Mouse.Click(uIButton1Button, new Point(35, 10));

    // Click '&Abort' button
    if(this.RedPathCodeParams.UITextBox1EditText=="2") //You could also use uIAbortButton.Exists instead
    Mouse.Click(uIAbortButton, new Point(51, 12));

    // Click 'button2' button
    Mouse.Click(uIButton2Button, new Point(56, 16));
}
```